# how to open a zipped folder shown as zip.xml file?

Tags: windows, zip, 7-zip, xml

I zipped some folders using winzip on my old laptop and copied to an external drive. The folders contain all types of files including xls, doc, ppt, etc. Now I am trying to open the zipped folders in the external drive on my new laptop. All the zipped folders show as zip.xml files. How to open/extract them? I have tried renaming the files to zip files, and extracting with 7zip, but it does not work. Thank you!

Comment: When you zipped folders, you should have `.zip` file as output which you should copy over, not `.xml` file. Basically you can't unzip from XML file.

Comment: If 7zip can't open the files, even with the right extension, then they're not valid .zip files-- they weren't created correctly. They may be useless.

Answer (score 1):

Open your external drive and you will see one folder named "SEERemovableStorageAcessUtility.exe" . Double click on the same folder. A new window will open and you can see the folder you want to download to your new PC. Right click on the same and you get an option to decrypt the same as your desired location. It will ask for the password which will be the password given at the time of encrypting the file.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to open these `zip.xml` files with a web browser or a text editor to confirm they really are XML. If this is the case, you will not be able to extract anything from them. Search for actual archives on your drive, or recreate them if you still have access to your old laptop.

If those `zip.xml` files are binary and begin with `PK` letter (which is the ZIP signature), you will probably be able to access the contents once you rename them to `.zip`